# Combining on('click') with $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

First time posting here:
I want to know if it's possible to do this. If not what's the best approach. All I want is to attach click events to a list of anchor links and use $.get() to reload the icons. There is reason I am trying to do this is because when I use the usual $(this).on('click'), it works fine but the reloaded anchor links don't respond to the js script any more:

```
var wishlistBtn = $('.zoa-wishlist');

wishlistBtn.each(function(){
    $(document).on('click', $(this), function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('href');

        $.get(url,function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
            if(textStatus == 'success'){

                $('div#product-button-group').load(location.href + ' div#product-button-group > *'); //Refresh the anchor links
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: You only need one event handler: `$(document).on("click", ".zoa-wishlist", function(event) { ... });`

Comment: Yes I get you, but when I do it this way the click event fires for all the links with the class ".zoa-wishlist" but what I expected to have is for the click event to only fire for the current link(with class zoo-wishlist) I clicked on. I have 5 different links with the same class "zoa-wishlist". i hope you get me?

Comment: The "click" and the "event" are the same thing. You don't have to do something with the stuff you clicked on, as the event is already the clicking.

Comment: @Pointy, Ok I get you now. Thanks for the feedback. It worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
$(document).on('click', ".zoa-wishlist", function(){
   /* ... */
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I think I now understand how it works.